# Добавить маршрут в таблицу маршрутизации

Tags: сеть, shell, маршрутизация, bash

Какими способами можно добавить новый маршрут (дефолтный или к определенной подсети) и изменять его?

Comment: Операционка какая?

Comment: unix (Solaris)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда как обычно:

> route [-fn] add | delete | get[net|host|default] [destination][gateway]

Отличие от юникс-команды - отсутствие `gw` перед шлюзом

Добавляя сеть необходимо указать маску:

> route add net 192.168.68.0 128.50.1.250 1 -netmask 255.255.255.192

Добавить дефолтный маршрут:

> route add default 196.168.0.1

Для сброса всей таблицы:

> route flush

Чтобы добавить постоянный маршрут, воспользуйтесь аргументом `-p`

Для редактирования, удалить, потом заново создать, я подозреваю.